# Qt original value of translated(internationalized) text

Tags: qt, internationalization, default, multilingual

ok, here is my problem.
I have a multilingual app. I translate the ui with lupdate and lrelease.

I have some options the user can edit, and he edits them from the input selection dialog. The values are for example "Quality" and "Speed".

Now, I'd like to replace those values with their translations.

Later, when I check the values of the option, I want to use only the original value. For instance: I have to check if value == "Speed", but if the language is not set to English, I will not have the "Speed" value in the selection dialog, but the string with the translation of "Speed".

How can I access the default (English) value from code, if the ui is already set to another language?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding correctly, you can just set the English value as a constant and refer to it.

```
const char* kEnglishKey = "Speed";
...
if (value == tr(kEnglishKey)) {
  ...
  DoSomeThingWith(kEnglishKey);
}
```

`tr` is a runtime, not compile-time, operation.

Comment: thanks. but the problem is in the dialog. I load translated values into it. But it returns selected text as output. Translated text that is

Comment: Right, so `tr(kEnglishKey)` will return the translated value, which you can test against the selection. That's why I mentioned that `tr` is a runtime activity. Your code still contains the English text but looks it up at runtime. Maybe I'm not understanding the problem. If you post some code that is not working, maybe I would have a better idea where things are going wrong.

Comment: can I just use if (value == tr("Speed")), or does it have to be constant?

Comment: You can just use `tr("Speed")`. I just had it in a constant because it sounded like you might need the untranslated value as well. Then you don't have any "magic strings," in case you change "Speed" to "Velocity" down the road or something like that.